# Continuity of $f(x, y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{|x|} +y^2}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Assume that $f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is defined by $f(0,0)=0$ and, for every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$,
>   $$f(x, y)={xy \over {\sqrt{|x|} + y^2}}.$$
>   I have to check whether the function is continuous at $(0,0)$ or not.

When we worked in the one-dimensional-space, we simply took a look at

$$\lim_{x\to 0_+} f(x),\qquad\lim_{x\to 0_-} f(x),$$

and when the values existed and furthermore the equation

$$\lim_{x\to 0_+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0_-} f(x)$$

held, then $f$ was continuous in $0$.

When I would apply the same algorithm on this case, then

$$\lim_{x\to 0_+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0_+} {{xy \over \sqrt{|x|} + y^2} = 0} $$

since the numerator converges to $0$, as well as

$$\lim_{x\to 0_-} {{xy \over \sqrt{|x|} + y^2} = 0} $$

for the same reason, such that

$$\lim_{x\to 0_+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0_-} f(x),$$

and thus, the function would be continuous at $0$. But since this seems a little bit too easy to me, I wondered if you could help me out on this one.

Comment: @Did: It appears you're misinterpreting the original question. Read the comments. In particular, you just mis-edited the title.

Comment: So, I edited the body, it should be clearer now. :-)

Comment: Is this what I have to prove?

Comment: @Julian Your instincts are correct in thinking what you did is just a bit too easy. I see two major issues: 1. You're not considering $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(f(x,y)\right)$, you're instead looking at the one variable limit $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(f(x,y)\right)$ and 2. In one dimension, you're allowed to just look at the left and right limits because those two sides are the only ways from which you can approach a point (in this case $0$), however in two dimensions you can approach the origin from a multitude of ways: (Continues in the next comment).

Comment: Yes since if $|x| \to 0$  and $|y| \to 0$ and then if $|f(x,y)|\to 0$ we can say that the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y) = 0$ is well-explained.

Comment: from the left, from the right, from above, from below, from the diagonals, from several weird and irregular ways, in fact you can do it from an infinitude of ways. Too correctly extrapolate the technique to a multidimensional space, this is what you would have to do. But this is unpractical. In one dimension your goal would be to find the limit at the origin, here it's the same: determine if $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(f(x,y)\right)$ exists, and if it does, if it equals $f(0,0)$.

Comment: But why did Did choose $\sqrt{|x|} * |y|$? Shouldn't I also be able to prove $|f(x, y)| \le |x| * |y|$ then?

Comment: @Julian What Did did was to find a function $g$ such that "obviously" $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(g(x,y)\right)=0$ and for all $(x,y)$ around the origin the inequality $|f(x,y)|\leq |g(x,y)|$ holds, because these two conditions imply that $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(f(x,y)\right)=0=f(0,0)$. It happens that $|f(x,y)|\leq |x|+|y|$ isn't always true near the origin, for instance take $x=y=\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: But if it does hold for ${{\sqrt|x|} * |y|}$, then it should also hold for $|x| * |y|$, shouldn't it? Just wonderwing why he chose this function in particular. :-)

Comment: To message someone directly, type "@Person'sUsername" within your message. For example, if you want to ask Did to explain what he did you could type `"Can you explain to me why you chose $\sqrt{|x|}|y|$ instead of $|xy|$, @Did?"`

Comment: @Did, can you explain to me why you chose $\sqrt{|x|}|y|$ instead of $|xy|$?

Comment: @Julian By the way, I edited my comment right after you next-to-last comment. Maybe that helps. Also note that where I typed $|x|+|y|$, I meant $|x||y|$. **Edit:** You should remove the double quotes if you want the ping to Did to work.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't seem to work. :D

Comment: Well, I guess I understood your approaches. Thanks for all the amazing answers! Wish our tutorials would have such a quality. :-)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt "Yes" as in "Yes the post correctly proves that the limit at (0,0) is 0"? Then I squarely disagree (and I cannot help to wonder which service you are rendering the OP by letting them believe that their flawed approach is correct).

Comment: Where should I start then? I already tried a lot, but it didn't work out. For example, I simplified the inequality to $1 \over |\sqrt{|x|} + y^2|$ $\le$ $\sqrt{|x|} \over |x| $, but this still doesn't give me much, does it?

Comment: @Did Could you help me out?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did, and like I said, I already tried to simplifly the inequality, but this doesn't give me much yet. I wondered if you could give me a hint how to start here.

Comment: After I pointed you twice at the very simple inequality which completely solves your question and you showed nothing of your try to prove it (for the record, simplifying a fraction does the job...) but turned instead to meta for a thinly disguised call to arms? Certainly not! Sorry but one cannot have its cake and eat it. Deleting my previous comments.

Comment: When I wrote the meta-post, I wasn't refering to you in any sense. The meta-post refered to another situation that I experienced a while ago - I deleted it though, since it was indeed kind of a dumb question to ask. Nontheless, I did solve the inequality now. I just had to write the right fraction as $1 \over \sqrt{|x|}$, which makes the inequality obvious since $y^2 \ge 0.$ Sorry, I simply have my issues with inequalities, I feel very insecure about solving them. That's why I kept asking. I didn't mean to offend you. :-)